# how to change edit box focus when text deleted in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 3 EditTexts for password field. Each can contain only one digit. I have implemented request focus when inputting the password. But how do I change focus from one EditText to another when I am deleting the digits?

Comment: Use textwatcher on edittexts.

Comment: go with onTextChange listener on Editfield,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a best practice for using edittext with one password.

```
et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code1);
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code2);
et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code3);

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                et2.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    });

    et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                et3.requestFocus();
            } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                et2.clearFocus();
                et1.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

You have to manage this way.